# Smart pointers as an alternative to QObject::deleteLater()

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, smart-pointers

So I have got a function which makes a network request:

```
void MyClass::makeRequest()
{
    ApiRequest* apiRequest = new ApiRequest();

    apiRequest->makeRequest();
    connect(apiRequest, &ApiRequest::requestFinished, this, &MyClass:onApiRequestFinished);
}
```

Since I need the object `apiRequest` to survive until my request is finished I then call:

```
void MyClass:onApiRequestFinished()
{
    // do my stuff
    // now I can delete my request object ((retrieved using sender()) using deleteLater()
}
```

Now since I am not using Qt parent-child system in this case how can I manage the memory using C++11 smart pointers instead of calling `deleteLater()`?

Comment: In my experience it's better not to try to mix Qt's parent-child system with smart pointers; that is, you're life will be less painful if you use Qt's system for handling QObject-derived objects and smart-pointers only for non-QObject-derived objects.

Comment: In addition to Jeremy: You shouldn't delete things explicitly (by `delete` or something comparable) if it is pointed by a smart pointer. Usually, the smart pointers are explicitly dedicated to manage the life-time of their pointees. (exluding the weak pointer which shouldn't ever used alone).

Comment: For me, *parent-child system* is not related to `deleteLater`, because the system is cleaning the children directly. The use of `deleteLater` is related to *signal-slot system*. So the fact that you don't use the *parent-child system* has nothing to do with the choice of using or not `deleteLater` in my opinion. And you **do use** the *signal-slot system*.

Comment: Yes I understand. The only reason I was asking is to know how would this situation be handled with smart pointers. How can I make an object survive until the slot is triggered.

Comment: More specifically I want to know if there is a way for a `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` to survive until the signal is triggered and then getting deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can solve this with C++ smart pointers without storing the `apiRequest` object in some container until `requestFinished` is triggered.

Maybe an alternative would be to create an `ApiRequest::finished()` method to use as the `receiver` of the signal, then pass `this` to `ApiRequest`'s constructor so `finished()` can call `MyClass::onApiRequestFinished()`, and then have `finished()` call `delete this` after `onApiRequestFinished()` exits, eg:

```
void MyClass::makeRequest()
{
    ApiRequest* apiRequest = new ApiRequest(this);
    apiRequest->makeRequest();
}

void MyClass::onApiRequestFinished()
{
    // do my stuff
}

...

ApiRequest::ApiRequest(MyClass *cls)
    : m_cls(cls)
{
    connect(this, &ApiRequest::requestFinished, this, &ApiRequest::finished);
}

void ApiRequest::finished()
{
    m_cls->onApiRequestFinished();
    delete this;
}
```

Not sure how feasible this is with Qt, but maybe worth a try.

Comment: But this doesn't really offer a better solution than my current one and ties `ApiRequest` with `MyClass` only. In my final slot I can get the `ApiRequest` object by: `auto apiRequest = qobject_cast<ApiRequest*>(sender());` and then call `deleteLater()` on it.